# yasnippet: problems with text-mode snippets

Tags: yasnippet

The snippets in the  `text-mode` subdir are authomatically loaded when I use certain other modes (e.g. latex-mode, cc-mode, ess-mode, etc). There is any way to stop loading snippets of parents mode?

For example, I'd like that when I work on an html file, only snippets defined under the for the html-mode are loaded in the YASnippet menu.

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/issues/580?

Comment: yes I read that github discussion on the linked discussions... no solution was found.